# Is there a block to print post link standalone in a block theme?

Tags: posts, theme-development, themes, templates, block-editor

I know we can print post property (e.g. title or date) wrapped into the link to the post by using a block with the attribute `"isLink":true` i.e.

```
<!-- wp:post-title {"level":1, "isLink":true} /-->
```

But is there a "built-in" block to print post link standalone?

Something like

```
<a href="<!-- wp:post-permalink {} /-->">Link to a post</a>
```

None of the following options work:

```
<!-- wp:post-permalink {} /-->
<!-- wp:post-link {} /-->
<!-- wp:post-url {} /-->
<!-- wp:post-path {} /-->
```

Comment: Are there anybody knows how to fix this issue?